# Cannot access Shiny App on a local server

Tags: r, deployment, ubuntu-14.04, shiny, rstudio-server

I have a shiny app on a local server (ubuntu) which uses a dataset which is also there in the server. It's working fine when I am running its code on the server, but when I am accessing the shiny app from another system (windows 8) it is giving this error...

"An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification"

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So have a look on the log-file
`/var/log/shiny-server/`